# how do i create a prompt in javascript with 3 checkboxes/radio buttons as choices?

Tags: javascript, prompt

How do I create a javascript prompt box where you have to select 1 of 3 choices? I'm looking to do something similar to a html form's radio buttons except within a javascript prompt.

Comment: i don't think this is possible.

Comment: the above comment is in reference to an actual `prompt()` call. Of course there are other ways to mimic this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use jQuery and do a 3 button dialog().  Check out this ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/ZKghP/)***:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({

    autoOpen: true,
    buttons: {

        Yes: function() {

            alert("Yes!");
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        No: function() {

            alert("No!");
            $(this).dialog("close");

        },
        Maybe: function() {

            alert("Maybe!");
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }

    },
    width: "400px"

});
```

Answer (score 2):

This can't be achieved natively as `.prompt()`. This functionality requires more advanced JS. Here are some libs to mess with:

1. [jQuery UI (dialog)](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog)
2. [jQuery Tools - Overlay](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/overlay/)

Could be more adequate ones out there. Been a while using such stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this from an "alert" box if thats what you mean.. But you could use any number of libraries to create a popup window which is basically just a  and do your form within there.

You could then tie a button or whatever to a function which closes the box and parses the form into your structures within Javascript.